# Dot convention in Magnetically coupled circuits

Tags: current, mutual-inductance

[image]

The book says that the for loop 2, the KVL is \$-j3 I_{1} + (12+j6)I_{2}=0\$ , but the loop 2 leaves the dot in its coil. Isn't it supposed to be \$-j3I_{1} + (12-j6)I_{2} =0\$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**The dot only determines the polarity of the mutual voltage, it won't affect other directions in the calculation.** In figure (b), it shows the equivalent circuit take into the mutual voltage. Because the direction of \$I_{1}\$ in loop 1 is flow into coil 1, and the direction of \$I_2\$ is defined to flow out from coil 2. So the mutual voltage's polarity in loop 2 is positive at the dot side.

Answer (score 0):

equation on loop 1 is
j(5-4)i1-j(4)i2=12<0
equation on loop 2 is
(12+6j)i2-3ji1=0
now equating we get
i1=(2-4j)i2
applyng this on loop 1 equation we get
i2=2.91<14.03
and
i1=13.001<-49
hence solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).